# how to avoid logging call stack when exception raised in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

We are raising exception using below code:

```
[NSException raise:@"ExceptionName" format:@"XYZ"];
```

when exception raised , call stack also logs in console. we don't want log the call stack in console. How to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa does not mix very well with exceptions (idiomatic C++ is another story). You should *generally* consider exceptions as non-recoverable in Cocoa. As such, you should **REALLY** consider another (more idiomatic) form of error handling in Cocoa. Thus, the short answer is: "Don't throw/raise exceptions, unless you don't intend on recovering".

---

Still not satisfied?

You have the ability catch exceptions and try to continue:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static void A() {
    [NSException raise:@"ExceptionName" format:@"XYZ"];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        @try {
            A();
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"e=mc%p", e);
            NSLog(@"What I meant to say is: %@", e);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the frameworks provide some high level entries and customization for your purposes, [outlined here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/ControllingAppResponse.html) -- You can set a mask to customize log levels, or set your own uncaught exception handler.